# First project in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, windows-server-2008

I have successfully completed my first project in an `ASP.NET Core` application using Connector/NET Core to explore the possibility to run this application on any .NET Core

This is the [tutorial](https://insidemysql.com/getting-started-with-asp-net-core-and-mysql-connectornet/)

This project work correctly on http://localhost:62954/Tablename

Now I need publish the project on the `windows server 2008` for sharing on the web this work

On the server I have installed [dotnet-sdk-3.1.300-win-x64.exe](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/73718445-e2bd-40b7-b698-e8a9ac65f4e5/0816570f697c4e8f1b53ecfb33eaed7f/dotnet-sdk-3.1.300-win-x64.exe)

I have copied the folder and file from project local to remote server `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnetcore\mvccore`

but if get on the browser the link http://mywebsite/aspnetcore/mvccore/views/tablename/Index.cshtml 
the return is `page not found`

isn't copying the local file and folders on the server enough for the project to work?

I am server administrator... maybe do I have to configure `IIS`?

can the new configuration create problems to the existing one on `IIS`?

how to do resolve this?

can you help me, please?

Comment: According to this guide [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) only Windows Server 2012 and later is supported for hosting .net core applications on IIS

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski hi, thanks for help. this is not good news... if there is no other possibility I ask my hosting service to upgrade from server 2008 to 2012. I developed the project on windows 10 without problem, and I didn't know that it only works on 2012 server... ;(

Comment: Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2 are no longer supported by Microsoft. I'd highly recommend moving to a more recent server OS. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/windows-server-2008

Comment: thanks but the migration to a more recent server OS my hosting provider has to do and it's not available to this

Comment: http://mywebsite/aspnetcore/mvccore/views/tablename/Index.cshtml , is it correc url. i hope this is correct one:http://mywebsite/tablename/Index.cshtml

Comment: @Always_a_learner This type of page is not available.
Description: The requested page type is not available because the administrator did not specify a manager or because access to this page type was explicitly prohibited. The extension '.cshtml' may be incorrect. Check the URL below and make sure it is spelled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need IIS for that. But, since you have a .NET Core App, why wouldn't you use Docker to avoid environment problems? It's very easy to configure with Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Docker? I do not know Docker, please explain. thanks

Comment: It's not that hard to get started. You don't have to be afraid :) With docker you could avoid environment problems, since you would work with the same environment in your local machine as the application runs in production. Please, take a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: But work on Windows Server 2008 R2 ? @PavelAnikhouski  say windows server 2012 or later

Comment: Actually no haha. If you really need to use it on that version of Windows, you have to use .Net Core 2.2 or lower (like says here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/install/dependencies?tabs=netcore22&pivots=os-windows). After that, you can install dotnet core cli and run as a Windows service or use IIS to host it. I would prefer to use IIS.

Comment: Ok. I have setting my project for run on dotnet-sdk-2.2.207-win-x64.exe for Windows Server 2008 R2 SP2, And now? How to do for run on IIS 7? i have to install dotnet-sdk-2.2.207-win-x64.exe on the server or it is enough dotnet-sdk-3.1.300-win-x64.exe? Any suggestion, please? I don't understand because not error when installing dotnet-sdk-3.1.300-win-x64.exe on  Windows Server 2008 R2 SP2....

Comment: It might actually work, I can't prove you it doesn't work with 3.1. That's just what the doc says. You should follow this tutorial to deploy with IIS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Just to know, that machine you have Windows Server 2008 R2 SP2, you have it locally or are u using some sort of cloud?

Comment: using locally machine with Windows Server 2008 R2 SP2

Answer (score 0):

[Activate MVC Web site on IIS 7 Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154348/activate-mvc-web-site-on-iis-7-windows-server-2008-r2-enterprise-sp2)

https://forums.asp.net/t/2167474.aspx?First+project+in+an+ASP+NET+Core+3+1+application