# Activate MVC Web site on IIS 7 Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have create a new ASP.NET Core 2.1 project empty on Visual Studio 2019

This is generated by a line in the Startup.cs file

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    }
}
```

The application can serve static files HTML from the wwwroot folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The project working on localhost

[image]

I need published it to a folder on remote server with SO Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP2.

I had IIS 7 installed on server.

I installed .Net 4.5.2 and asp.net 2.1 core runtime and asp.net core 3.1 runtime on the server 2008 R2 SP2

I copied the folder contiaining my published Web site to `\inetpub\wwwroot` on the server.

With this post I configured MVC website in IIS.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1168712/How-to-Quickly-Configure-your-MVC-Website-in-IIS

[image]

But on the server the return is

[image]

When click on wwwroot project folder

[image]

What do I do to give the Web site a URL and otherwise make it active as a Web site?

Maybe I have to install more on the server?

[image]

**update**

Installed on the server

[image]

[image]

[image]

it finally worked thanks to everyone for the support and help

[image]

Comment: VS hides all details from you https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3 But once on IIS you need to strictly follow the steps such as `dotnet publish` and ASP.NET Core module. Well, tons for you to learn from various tutorials.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for reply, sorry but I on't understand your suggestion vs my problem... moreover, the .cshtml pages do not work on the server 2008 R2... could you help me please?

Comment: The problem you faced is simply because you don't fully understand how IIS and ASP.NET Core work together. You have to know every words of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1 and something behind the scene, but that's rather lengthy to go over. BTW, never use a URL with .cshtml. ASP.NET Core MVC apps follow certain URL patterns and none of them expose a .cshtml page explicitly.

Comment: @LexLi Ok, I know this link but the operating systems are supported Windows 7 or later Windows Server 2012 R2 or later... I work with Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP2 and it cannot be updated, if open on the server http://localhost:901/ without cshtml. the return is the list of folders of project.... thanks

Comment: About why localhost link failed, you can get some ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142003/set-homepage-in-asp-net-mvc The MVC URL patterns I said above do not include `/` by default, so IIS won't be able to show you anything (and you probably was frightened by the 404.13 error page and went on to enable directory listing. That's wrong and disable it please).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should use `DotNet build`, `DotNet publish` command to publish our website rather than copy the project file to the website directory.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli
In `Visual studio`, we just need to use the below menu to publish website since VS is a strong, powerful IDE.
[image]
Select folder and type the physical path of the website.
[image]
At last, we need to install the corresponding Asp.Net hosting bundles(2.1 version instead of 3.1) in order to host Asp.net core web application in IIS.
[image]
Result.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Many thanks for help. But if publish my project on server from VS is the existing IIS configuration deleted? Please see **update** image in question. Under **Default Web Site** I have multiple application web and I don't have to delete them

Comment: @UncleVince  In the `Advanced` of the above publish menu, you could opt in to whether delete the existing file.

Comment: it finally worked thanks to everyone for the support and help!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing https://dotnet.microsoft.com/permalink/dotnetcore-current-windows-runtime-bundle-installer

Read more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio